# DeltaSpike CDI Testing + NPE Faces Context

Tags: testing, cdi, jsf-2.2, deltaspike

I want to implement a CDI Test with DeltaSpike. But when I try to call a function that depends on the Faces Context, I yield a Null Pointer Exception.

Do I need to mock the class or can it be initialized in a better way?

```
@RunWith(CdiTestRunner.class)
public class DeltaSpikeTest{

    @Inject
    private WindowContext windowContext;

    @Inject 
    private TestBean testBean;

    @Test
    public void main() {
        this.windowContext.activateWindow("w1");

        testBean.methodThatUsesFacesContext(); // NPE
    }
}
```

Every help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MyFaces-Test and one of the Adapters provided by DeltaSpike.
Then you can use calls to JSF like in https://github.com/os890/ee6-ds-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/org/os890/demo/ee6/test/PageBeanTest.java

Comment: If you ask such questions on their Mailing-List, you will get answers way faster.

Comment: Hello Dar, thank you for your answer. I already found a similar answer from you to this topic and tried to solve it with this. Probably the solution is in this answer, but I can't find it. Could you be more precise? Thank you in advance!

Comment: see https://github.com/os890/ee6-ds-demo/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.deltaspike.testcontrol.spi.ExternalContainer as well as the maven-config for myfaces-test see https://github.com/os890/ee6-ds-demo/blob/master/pom.xml#L139